# How to create new page for my custom plugin in wp?

Tags: wordpress

I am creating new plugin in wp.This plugin catalogue photo
For everyone item i want to create one page per One item.

How create new page for items?

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code when you want to add page during perticualr hook.

```
$page_id = wp_insert_post( 
                        array( 
                            'post_title'     => 'Page Title',
                            'post_name'      => 'Page Title',
                            'post_content'   => 'Page Content',
                            'post_status'    => 'publish',
                            'post_author'    => 1, // or "1" (super-admin?)
                            'post_type'      => 'page',
                            'menu_order'     => 1,
                            'comment_status' => 'closed',
                            'ping_status'    => 'closed',
                        ) 
                    );
```